# When is there a need to use a reasoner like jena when developing a knowledge-based QA system?

Tags: jena, google-knowledge-graph, nlp-question-answering, reasoner

In my opinion :

Query the answer from the RDF 3-tuples, if no answer ,then try a reasoner.

Use the reasoner to complete knowledge graph off-line to save online query time.

Comment: Actually, Jena is not a reasoner. Why do you answer the question you asked in the title?

Comment: but jena can be used to reason, jena's java API <ReasonerRegistry.getOWLReasoner()> . So what reasoner do you use?

Comment: I prefer Openllet https://github.com/Galigator/openllet